# Django: auto-updating a drop down causes "form.is_valid()" return false

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-forms

while requesting the page for 1st time , I dynamically update and send "keywords" for present dates.
Suppose "01-10-2013" to "02-10-2013".
Dropdown has 2 keywords "cat" and "mouse"
This is how my page gets populated on page load.

Now,
I need to update dropdown to keywords according to date selected by user:
Suppose     "20-09-2013" to "02-10-2013"

```
$("#id_keyword").empty();
$.each(data, function(i, value) {
        $('#id_keyword').append($('<option>').text(value).attr('value', value));
                                   });
```

This works fine and my dropdown gets updated to new keywords.

```
"elephant", "tiger", "lion", "rat"
```

Now when i make a request to server,

```
"form.is_valid()" returns false,
```

and

```
logging.debug("%s"%form)
```

this gives the onload values of dropdown ie, "cat", "mouse".

What should I do??

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
forms.CharField(required=False, widget = forms.Select(attrs={'display':'none'}),initial=None)
```

in place of

```
forms.ChoiceField(required=False, choices = CHOICE)
```

in your form.